# Python program to delete all the rows and columns with all zeros and print the remaining matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any program possible with a complexity less than O(m*n)? The input is in the form as the first line contains M*N and the next M lines each containing N integers
For example

```
4 4
1 0 3 4
0 0 0 0
4 0 6 8
4 0 2 4
```

The output should be:

```
1 3 4
4 6 8
4 2 4
```

Comment: Your input data is numpy array or a list of lists?

Comment: It's a list of lists.

Comment: then the first solution should work well for you :) or if you are open to using numpy, try the second one as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by individually filtering rows and columns with all values equal to 1 but checking if `set(row or column)!={0}`

```
arr = [[1, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 6, 8],
       [4, 0, 2, 4]]

rows = [i for i in arr if set(i)!={0}]
cols = [i for i in zip(*rows) if set(i)!={0}]
arr_new = [list(i) for i in zip(*cols)]
print(arr_new)
```

```
[[1, 3, 4], 
 [4, 6, 8], 
 [4, 2, 4]]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you are ok with using numpy then you can do this a bit more easily -

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(arr)
arr[~(arr==0).all(0)][:,~(arr==0).all(1)]
```

```
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [4, 6, 8],
       [4, 2, 4]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but can you please tell me the complexity of this first program?